# TypeError: string indices must be integers with sklearn version 0.24.2

Tags: python, scikit-learn, typeerror

I was running the following code with sklearn 0.22:

```
def regress_models(X, y):
    

    scoring = {'r2': 'r2',
              'mae': 'neg_mean_absolute_error'}

     # define models
    models, names, mape, r2, mae = list(), list(), list(), list(), list()
   
    # LR
    models.append(LinearRegression())
    names.append('LR')

    #Lasso
    models.append(Lasso())
    names.append('LA')


    #RF
    models.append(RandomForestRegressor(random_state=42))
    names.append('RF')


    for i in range(len(models)):
        
        # define evaluation procedure
        cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=4, random_state=None)
        pipeline = Pipeline([('model', models[i])])
        scores = cross_validate(pipeline, X, y, scoring=scoring,
                                 cv=cv, return_train_score=True, n_jobs=-1)

        mape=list(scores["test_mape"])
        r2=list(scores['test_r2'])
        mae=list(scores['test_mae'])

        # summarize and store
        print('{}  R^2:{}, MAE:{}'.format(names[i], mean(r2), mean(mae)))
```

All works fine until I upgraded to sklearn 0.24 and now I'm getting the following error:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-309-cf93f9c077fa> in <module>
----> 1 regress_clamp(X_rcsi, y_rcsi)

<ipython-input-308-67a5841bff3d> in regress_clamp(X, y)
     38         pipeline = Pipeline([('model', models[i])])
     39         scores = cross_validate(pipeline, X, y, scoring=scoring,
---> 40                                  cv=cv, return_train_score=True, n_jobs=-1)
     41 
     42         mape=list(scores["test_mape"])

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in cross_validate(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, return_train_score, return_estimator, error_score)
    239     if callable(scoring):
    240         scorers = scoring
--> 241     elif scoring is None or isinstance(scoring, str):
    242         scorers = check_scoring(estimator, scoring)
    243     else:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in _aggregate_score_dicts(scores)
   1503     for n_train_samples, partial_train in partitions:
   1504         train_subset = train[:n_train_samples]
-> 1505         X_train, y_train = _safe_split(estimator, X, y, train_subset)
   1506         X_partial_train, y_partial_train = _safe_split(estimator, X, y,
   1507                                                        partial_train)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
   1503     for n_train_samples, partial_train in partitions:
   1504         train_subset = train[:n_train_samples]
-> 1505         X_train, y_train = _safe_split(estimator, X, y, train_subset)
   1506         X_partial_train, y_partial_train = _safe_split(estimator, X, y,
   1507                                                        partial_train)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1502         fit_params = {}
   1503     for n_train_samples, partial_train in partitions:
-> 1504         train_subset = train[:n_train_samples]
   1505         X_train, y_train = _safe_split(estimator, X, y, train_subset)
   1506         X_partial_train, y_partial_train = _safe_split(estimator, X, y,

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

It works again after I downgraded back to 0.22 but does anyone know what is causing this issue with the new version? Nothing else in my dataset or code had changed between the two versions of the module.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works on scikit-learn 0.24.1. The key issues were:

- The code was using `StratifiedKFold` instead of `KFold`, which throws an error given that the target is continuous as this is a regression task.
- The code was attempting to extract the `'test_mape'` from the cross validation results, but only the R2 and the MAE were included in the `scoring` dictionary.

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression, Lasso
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate, KFold
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import numpy as np
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)
# 0.24.1

def regress_models(X, y):

    # define metrics
    scoring = {'r2': 'r2', 'mae': 'neg_mean_absolute_error', 'mape': 'neg_mean_absolute_percentage_error'}

    # define models
    models, names, mape, r2, mae = list(), list(), list(), list(), list()

    # LR
    models.append(LinearRegression())
    names.append('LR')

    # Lasso
    models.append(Lasso())
    names.append('LA')

    # RF
    models.append(RandomForestRegressor(random_state=42))
    names.append('RF')

    for i in range(len(models)):

        # define evaluation procedure
        cv = KFold(n_splits=4, random_state=None)
        pipeline = Pipeline([('model', models[i])])
        scores = cross_validate(pipeline, X, y, scoring=scoring, cv=cv, return_train_score=True, n_jobs=-1)

        # calculate performance metrics
        mape = list(scores['test_mape'])
        r2 = list(scores['test_r2'])
        mae = list(scores['test_mae'])

        # summarize and store
        print('{}  R^2: {:%}, MAE: {:f}, MAPE: {:%}'.format(names[i], np.mean(r2), np.mean(mae), np.mean(mape)))

# test the function
X, y = make_regression(n_samples=1000, n_features=5, noise=10, random_state=42)
regress_models(X, y)
# LR  R^2: 97.421704%, MAE: -8.260329, MAPE: -75.592451%
# LA  R^2: 97.305603%, MAE: -8.371423, MAPE: -70.782377%
# RF  R^2: 88.443183%, MAE: -16.847307, MAPE: -135.300698%
```